# Prove the efficiency of repeated calls to successor() in binary trees?

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree, proof

I need a hint for this exercise from the CLRS Algorithms book:

> Prove that no matter what node we start at in a height-h binary search tree, *k* successive calls to Tree-Successor take *O(k+h)* time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Let `x` be the starting node and `z` be the ending node after `k` successive calls to TREE-SUCCESSOR.
- Let `p` be the simple path between `x` and `z` inclusive.
- Let `y` be the common ancestor of `x` and `z` that `p` visits.
- The length of `p` is at most `2h`, which is `O(h)`.
- Let `output` be the elements that their values are between `x.key` and `z.key` inclusive.
- The size of `output` is `O(k)`.
- In the execution of `k` successive calls to TREE-SUCCESSOR,
  the nodes that are in `p` are visited,
  and besides the nodes `x`, `y` and `z`,
  if a sub tree of a node in `p` is visited then all its elements are in `output`.
- So the running time is `O(h+k)`.

Comment: `In the execution of k successive calls to TREE-SUCCESSOR, the nodes that are in p are visited, and besides the nodes x, y and z` Can you please explain what is `y` here?

Comment: I added `y` to the answer.

Comment: @AviCohen. Thank you very much. So, I though `k` successive calls would mean to call the function of finding successor `k` times meaning that we would have `k` different functions each with its own recursive calls. I think, since finding successor for each would take `O(h)`, where `h` is the height, then we need `O(h)+...+O(h)` `k` times? P

Answer (score 3):

Hint: work out a small example, observe the result, try to extrapolate the reason.

To get started, here are some things to consider.

Start at a certain node, k succesive calls to Tree-Succcesor consititutes a partial tree walk. How many (at least and at most) nodes does this walk visit? (Hint: Think about key(x)). Keep in mind that an edge is visited at most twice (why?).

Final hint: The result is `O(2h+k)`.

Comment: A node is visited at most trice.